# combine lines from 2 prints to single line and insert into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

Hello everyone i currently have this:

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('http://store.steampowered.com/feeds/news.xml')

for i in range(10):
    print d.entries[i].title
    print d.entries[i].date
```

How would i go about making it so that the title and date are on the same line? Also it doesn't need to print i just have that in there for testing, i would like to dump this output into a mysql db with the title and date, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question doesn't match your title. I'd suggest changing the title to something like 'How do I insert two values into a MySQL database?'. And I'd suggest that you post your code for how you currently are using the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print on the same line, just add a comma:

```
print d.entries[i].title, # <- comma here
print d.entries[i].date
```

To insert to MySQL, you'd do something like this:

```
to_db = []
for i in range(10):
    to_db.append((d.entries[i].title, d.entries[i].date))

import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="me",passwd="pw",db="mydb")
c = conn.cursor()
c.executemany("INSERT INTO mytable (title, date) VALUES (%s, %s)", to_db)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your actual question: if you want to join two strings with a comma you can use something like this:

```
print d.entries[i].title + ', ' + str(d.entries[i].date)
```

Note that I have converted the date to a string using `str`.

You can also use string formatting instead:

```
print '%s, %s' % (d.entries[i].title, str(d.entries[i].date))
```

Or in Python 2.6 or newer use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

But if you want to store this in a database it might be better to use two separate columns instead of combining both values into a single string. You might want to consider adjusting your schema to allow this.